# A puzzling note

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, steganography

You find yourself trapped in a room with three painted doors; one yellow, one purple, one black. You know that only one leads out to safety while the others lead to your doom. You find a note.  On it is written

> [image: Note]

Being as obsessed as you are with riddles, ciphers and numbers, you are now confident which door to take.
Which door is it?

Here is a more readable copy with some hintful puctuation:

> "Last name" is the clue
>   A hint: from me to you
>   Once you're upon my name
>   A pattern I planned out
>   Will help you to get out
>   Now enjoy the game
>   - 3465 8127

Comment: second line of punctuation will probably help quite a bit

Comment: Look at that hint and remember my tags

Comment: Steganography tag added

Comment: can we have an exact translation of the note? into text. pics wont show

Comment: If you can’t see the image, it’s okay.  Just the text is technically all you need to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Should I read it as "minus" 3465 or "dash" 3465?

Comment: A dash.  It should be taken as the author’s signature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Full Answer:**

Following the major clues from commenter Caleb Devine...(thank you Caleb)

> Starting from the "I" in the center of the chart use the Ulam Spiral counter-clockwise, highlighting the prime numbers. It will reveal the color :) [image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :)

Comment: Well done! Also good job to @Caleb Devine.  Thank you all for playing at my first puzzle!

Comment: Nice job! Welcome to Puzzling

Comment: Was there any particular hint to tell you 1) Where to start 2) To go right first and 3) to go counter-clockwise?

Comment: @GendoIkari i followed the simplified version of the Spiral here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral . took a stab and started at what i thought was the center. turned out to be right

Comment: Look very closely at the “I”. Notice anything?  Or edit my question.  Once you got to the start I figured you could figure it out.  But most Ulam spirals I have seen follow this pattern.

Answer (score 8):

**Partial Answer:**

"From me to you" is

> "From E to U"

Since "Last Name" is the clue

> Substitute E with U, rearrange by 3465 8127 to get the new name "Stan Ulam"
> , a famous physicist and Mathematician who worked on the the Manhattan Project

"A pattern I planned out" refers to

> The Ulam Spiral. It's a pattern in prime numbers that you get when you put the prime numbers in a spiral. The interesting concentration of primes occur on the diagonals. Therefore I think we are supposed to put all the letters into a spiral, like the Ulam spiral.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Well-spotted! Hope you stick around and keep contributing!

Comment: I've tried putting all the letters in a spiral and taking a look at the primes + diagonals. Nothing has jumped out at me...yet.

Comment: I've tried that too in several ways. Maybe it's not the right approach. Since the pattern is on prime numbers I tried looking at the letters in prime positions. Nothing obvious emerges

Answer (score 6):

**Attempt at an Answer?**
A note that

> if we assume the numbers map to positions in the puzzle, it’s signed by “**STAN ELAM**”.

Then, taking from “Last name” is the clue:

> Last of “STAN ELAM” is **M**, take the middle door

Probably not that simple, but ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You are “partially” there

Comment: hmm... interesting...

Comment: can this be done to all the lines? and then something like anagram maybe

Comment: @smriti That would be neat, but not the right track.

Comment: "last name" is an anagram of "stan elam", does that help?

Comment: @Jordan.J.D of course not, "last name" is part of the question

Comment: @TrojanByAccident defnitely not a1z26

Comment: elam backwards is male?

Comment: no watch this be rot13 on stan elam

Comment: You have almost the name. Step two is to get the correct name which can be derived from a clue hidden in a wordplay.

Answer (score 4):

Found interesting that's why posting. Is it

> The **yellow** door ?

Found this.

> As OP has admitted Stan Elam (Figured out by [TrojanByAccident](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30376/trojanbyaccident)) is on the right track, last name will be **ELAM** which means forever in Hebrew.

And the hint in the riddle

> "A hint: from me to you" is a famous song by well known rock band [Beatles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles).

From this two points

> We get [Beatles forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatles_Forever), which is an unreleased song by Electric Light Orchestra also know as [ELO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Light_Orchestra) which is likely to say **yellow**.
>
>
>  And an intresting fact is that this song was intented to use in an album called **Secret Messages**.

Answer (score 2):

**An attempt at a clue:**

> <s>"From Me to You" denotes the Beatles song which came up in **1963**. So using the same technique *TrojanByAccident* used, 1963 leads to **lias** which could be interpreted as *alias*. So an alias of Stan Elam maybe? S Elam?</s>

**An attempt at a clue Pt 2:**

> <s>"From me to you" can be assumed as **[i]=>[u]** (me=I; you=U) which shows the sequence *ijklmnopqrstu* leading to 13 letters? Some cipher maybe?</s>

***"Maybe dumb or smart"* attempt Pt 3:**

> The anagrams for *elam* are: **alme, lame, leam, male, mela and meal**. 
>  So replacing me with "**you**" leads to: **alyou,layou, youla and youal?!?**. 
>  Or replacing me with "**u**" leads to: **alu, lau, ula and ual?!?**

## Answer attempt:

> The door is **purple**? 
>  **Theory:** 
>  1) Based on my third attempt, finding the anagram for stan+alu leads to *sultana* 
>  2) Searching for Sultana leads to *Sultana bird* which is a **purple** swamphen

Comment: Such a good attempt. But sadly not close. Though it’s true that “from me to you” is the part you need to figure out.

Comment: With your second attempt, you’re getting warmer, but it’s much simpler.

Comment: @user991003 Added a possible answer

Comment: So interesting. But no. The answer will feel more obvious when found.  But don’t give up.  None of your attempts so far are accurate, but attempts 2 & 3 are skirting the edge.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

Looking further in the text,

> Once you're upon my name
>
>  A pattern I planned out
>
>  Will help you to get out

This seems to imply that

> if we know the name we will recognise some kind of a pattern.

Maybe the first step is to

> figure out what pattern it is, and

then use either the numbers or the letter as a key to decode the other part.

> The actual message can be the numbers part as well, as either of the three answers is smaller than 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> First line: The clue IS the word "Last Name" rather then Stan Elam, since this is wordplay.
>  Second line: Perhaps its a literal words "me to you"

Comment: Sorry that’s not the wordplay. “Stan Elam” is on the right track.